# Windows 7 Logon Screen: Change Shutoff Button to Restart Button

Tags: windows-7, reboot, login-screen

Yes, I know Windows 7 support is ending really soon and there are plans to convert to Windows 10. However, in the meantime, I would still like to do this.

On the login screen, there is a button to shutoff the computer. To restart the computer, you need to click the drowpdown and select the restart option instead. Is there a way to make restart the default option?

I tried searching online and like 99% of what I found was just talking about how to change the login screen's background image. Most of the other pages where about autologin and how to remove the button altogether. I don't want to remove it, I just want to change it from shutdown to restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Login screen "power button" has no config parameter except (as you know) disabling/removing it or [change its appearance](https://www.oxhow.com/change-windows-7-logon-screen-background-button-set/). This simply wasn't implemented by Microsoft. I would guess this was mainly for security reasons. If the code is less complex the risk of intrusion is lower (which is a relevant factor at before the logon of authenticated users because simply speaking anyone has access at this point) - but it's just a guess.

However, you can enter a little deeper and modify the logon screen by modifying the windows code (or dll-files etc.) itself. There are quite a few threads out there, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186900/adding-command-button-to-windows-logon-screen). But if you wanna go this way superuser propable isn't the right community for these questions.

Comment: Andrew is asking for a method to change the SIGN-IN menu not the power button action.

Comment: @LightlySalted changed my answer, please review again.